# DataGrid textbox filtering does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have problem with DataGrid textbox filtering since I've change the way I do it.

There is big `ViewModel`, which instance is created in `MainWindow` during app initialization.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ...
    viewModel = new ViewModel();
    viewModel.Recipients = GetRecipients();
    ...
}
```

I don't know if it's good way to do it, but for me it's working so I stick with that. I'm doing stuff this way, because I wanted to load big data from database once at program start so other elements could use it entire time.
`GetRecipients` is just used for that.

This is how my `ViewModel` (important parts) looks like:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private ICollectionView recipientsView;

    private CultureInfo culture;

    private ICommand _command;

    private ObservableCollection<Recipient> _recipients;

    public ObservableCollection<Recipient> Recipients
    {
        get { return _recipients; }
        set
        {
            _odbiorcy = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Recipients");
        }
    }

    private bool _isEmpty;

    public bool IsEmpty
    {
        get { return _isEmpty; }
        set
        {
            _isEmpty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsEmpty");
        }
    }

    private string _filter;

    public string Filter
    {
        get { return _filter; }
        set
        {
            _filter = value;
            recipientsView.Refresh();
            OnPropertyChanged("Filter");
        }
    }

    private Recipient_selected;

    public Recipient Selected
    {
        get { return _selected; }
        set
        {
            _selected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Selected");
        }
    }



    public ViewModel()
    {
        Recipients = new ObservableCollection<Recipient>();
        recipientsView= CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Recipients);
        recipientsView.Filter = o => String.IsNullOrEmpty(Filter) ? true : ((Recipient)o).Name.IndexOf(Filter, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 ||
                                                                         ((Recipient)o).City.IndexOf(Filter, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 ||
                                                                         ((Recipient)o).Street.IndexOf(Filter, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 ||
                                                                         ((Recipient)o).PostCode.IndexOf(Filter, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 ||
                                                                         ((Recipient)o).ContactPerson.IndexOf(Filter, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
    }




    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}
```

And...

`Recipients.xaml`

```
<UserControl x:Class="DHL.Recipients"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DHL"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="460" d:DesignWidth="750">
<Grid Background="White">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="60" />
            <RowDefinition Height="350"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Label Content="Search recipient:" Margin="25,0,0,0"></Label>
            <TextBox x:Name="FilterTextBox" Text="{Binding Filter, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="145" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="25,25,0,0"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="RecipientsGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                      EnableColumnVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Recipients}" Height="350" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Selected,Mode=TwoWay}"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" MouseDoubleClick="Row_DoubleClick">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="250" Binding="{Binding Name,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Street" Width="150" Binding="{Binding Street,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="House Number" Width="150" Binding="{Binding HouseNumber,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Apartament Number" Width="150" Binding="{Binding ApartamentNumber,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Postal Code" Width="150" Binding="{Binding PostalCode,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="City" Width="150" Binding="{Binding City,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Contact Person" Width="150" Binding="{Binding ContactPerson, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Email" Width="150" Binding="{Binding Email, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Phone Number" Width="150" Binding="{Binding PhoneNumber, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <Button x:Name="CloseButton" Click="CloseButton_Click"
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,10" Width="100" Height="25" Content="Close"></Button>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

And `Recipients` class:

```
public partial class Recipients : UserControl
{

    ViewModel viewModel;

    public Recipients (ViewModel model)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.viewModel = model;
        this.DataContext = viewModel;
    }

    public Recipients ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel view = new ViewModel();
        this.DataContext = view;
    }

    private void CloseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var parent = this.Parent as Window;

        if (parent != null)
        {
            parent.DialogResult = true;
            parent.Close();
        }
    }

    private void Row_DoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        CloseButton_Click(this, null);
    }
}
```

I've tried to create new `Recipients` instance in both ways (with `ViewModel` in parameter and without it). Both stopped working after I've changed whole project (creating `ViewModel` instance once and use it in every place in project - there is part I'm still trying to deal with). I tought it may work, because of `PropertyChanged` but it seems I was wrong.

The question is: Is this good way to create `ViewModel` once instead of creating `ViewModel` in every UserControl I want to use it ? If it is, what's wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what's wrong with my code

You're filtering wrong collection.
Here's where collection and its view are initially created:

```
public ViewModel()
{
    Recipients = new ObservableCollection<Recipient>();
    recipientsView= CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Recipients);

    // rest of code not shown
}
```

Then you're assigning new instance to the collection:

```
// MainWindow ctor
viewModel.Recipients = GetRecipients();
```

Your grid is bound to the collection, not its view, and collection ultimately contains result of `GetRecipients`:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Recipients}"
```

To fix this, do the following:

1) Fix data binding. Bind grid to collection view, not the collection itself:

```
// view model
public ICollectionView RecipientsView
{ 
    get
    {
        if (recipientsView == null)
        {
            // DO NOT create collection view inside constructor
            recipientsView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Recipients);
            recipientsView.Filter = // filtering code here;
        }

        return recipientsView;
    }
}

<!-- DataGrid XAML -->
ItemsSource="{Binding RecipientsView}"
```

2) Make `Recipients` get-only. Usually you don't need to change collection *object reference* inside view model. You need to change collection content:

```
public ObservableCollection<Recipient> Recipients
{
    get
    {
        if (_recipients == null)
        {
            // DO NOT create collection inside constructor
            _recipients = new ObservableCollection<Recipient>();          
        }

        return _recipients;
    }
}
```

3) Change collection population code. Add `UpdateRecipients` method to view model:

```
   public void UpdateRecipients(IEnumerable<Recipient> newRecipients)
   {
       Recipients.Clear();

       foreach (var item in newRecipients)
       {
           Recipients.Add(item);
       }
   }
```

And call it on initialization:

```
viewModel = new ViewModel();
viewModel.UpdateRecipients(GetRecipients());
```

Comment: It's filtering again. Thank you for your help and advices.